# how to update the expiration date in the Docusign Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have tried to update the expiration date using the PUT Method for an In-Progress Envelope , but received the response as NULL

```
<envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
                    <notification>
                            <expirations>
                                        <expireEnabled>true</expireEnabled><expireAfter>360</expireAfter><expireWarn>20</expireWarn>
                            </expirations>
                    </notification>
                </envelope>
```

Output:

Comment: What is your use-case exactly, did you set the wrong expiration when you created the envelope?  I'm not sure you can update it through the API.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can update the expiration date through the API.  This is configured one time and sending time.